# Display content using Django template

Tags: python, json, django

I have a json value sent to django template  as below, I would couldn't get a solution to display each key value pairs in a table format.

Json:

```
elem: {
     k1: v1,
     x: {
          abc: {
                k2: v2,
                k3, v3
               },
          efg: {
                k4, v4
               }
        }
     y: {
         qwe: {
               k5, v5
              }
        }
     }
```

From the above json that is sent from Django Views page to the remplate, the front end page should display something like below in table format,

```
k1           v1
x
abc
k2           v2
k3           v3
efg
k4           v4
y
qwe
k5           v5
```

Please note that the output has one row for each (K,V) pairs and one row for each key (without its value) which has a json object as its value.

Only using normal iteration like below needs all the keys in json to have a value which is of primitive type(string or numbers), but above json example has json object itself as a value for some keys.

```
{% for k, v in elem.items %}
  <tr>
      <td> {{k}}</td>
      <td> {{v}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: It would be great if there is any possibility of calling the above code recursively within the template to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `{% for k, v in elem.items %}` you are iterating through dictionary keys, so I think you should convert your JSON object to python dictionary before sending it to template context, or the template logic become unnsessary complex.

You should convert it to "flat" python dict with only one level (without any "nested" dicts) - something like: `{"k1":"v1", "x":"", "abc":"", "k2":"v2", "k3": "v3"....}` it is better to do it with python and use simple  {% for k, v in elem.items %} in template, than trying to do render given JSON in template